# UWP app can't fully launch another UWP app?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

The UWP app I'm working on uses Launcher to launch another UWP app that I also wrote. Here's the code I'm using to launch the other app:

```
        var uriToLaunch = "testapp-mainpage://";

        var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);

        bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
```

So far, this code is able to launch the other app I wrote, but it just opens up the app window with the default blue background with an X in the middle, basically the default UWP splash screen. I've tried setting the URI to target the MainPage of the app, but no matter how I try to modify the URI, it just launches to the default splashscreen. The app I'm launching is just a very basic, default UWP app at the moment. What am I missing or doing wrong that it the app being launched doesn't fully initialize?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to modify the launched app to handle protocol activation. The default wizards generate an app.xaml.cs which handles typical activation via OnLaunched but not alternate activations via OnActivated:

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
    {
        ProtocolActivatedEventArgs eventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
        // TODO: Handle URI activation
        // The received URI is eventArgs.Uri.AbsoluteUri

        // You'll likely want to navigate to a page based on AbsoluteUri
        // If you just want to launch the main page you can call essentially
        // the same code as OnLaunched
    }
}
```

See [Handle URI activation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation#step-3-handle-the-activated-event) on MSDN for more details. See the [Association Launching Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AssociationLaunching) for a concrete example.

Comment: I tried implementing those examples but nothing happens still. It still launches the app and just hangs on the default splash screens. Some of the examples I tried implementing however did cause the launched app to crash almost immediately. But other than that, I can't get it to navigate to the main page.

Comment: What exactly did you implement? What code did you put where to navigate to the main page (my OnActivated doesn't actually do anything: you'll need to replace the TODO comments with your application-specific navigation code)? When you debugged the launched app did OnActivated get called? What happened then?

Comment: This is what I implemented: 

if (e.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
            {
                Frame rootFrame = new Frame();

                if (rootFrame.Content == null)
                {
                    if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage)))
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
                    }
                }

                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));

                // Ensure the current window is active
                Window.Current.Activate();
            }

Comment: The original code is based off a combination of these 2 examples: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-launch-an-UWP-app-5abfa878

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701484.aspx

Comment: Can you update your question with more details of what you have in your App.xaml.cs of the launched app now?

Comment: I got it to work, I just had to copy and modify a few things from the OnLaunched method.